# Backup files/folders from windows machine to remote windows machine using python

Tags: python, windows, backup, sftp, scp

I have few windows users that need to backup their files/folders to another remote machine (windows). Currently only local backup on own machine. I plan to automate the backup process to remote machine. I looks for some python script using scp, paramiko, ftps or  some other modules in python. Thus, I would like to get some advise the best practice to implement it, which method that able to fit the requirement. I'm not a python programmer but can understand a bit....a simple script will do... The plan is user can run the script by them self or automate using scheduler. User will get log message (success/fail/error/etc) and myself will get overall log message of the backup activity done by the user.
For now..i just exploring available solutions on the net and try to understand the method...
Thank you for your comments and advises.

---

User can backup any files/folders. If the backup content is same as previous it will be overwrites the old file/folder. User will be notified shall they want to proceed or not.

---

Update 1607.01
Rsync in windows10 machine require updated version ...unfortunately some of  Win10pro not able to update as per require. I will continue looking on the solution. Thanks

Comment: i suggest `rsync` instead of `python` - it checks which files changed and send only changed files. And if you want to automate or create GUI then use Python with `rsync`

Comment: hi....the req want to use python...but i will look into rsync too...thanks

Comment: if you are not programmer then writing all from scratch can be big task - and `rsync` even hidden in Python code can resolve some problems. You can also use other similar program - like [rclone](https://rclone.org/) which can also backup to many servers like Microsoft OneDrive, Google Drive, Dropbox, Amazon S3, etc.

Comment: Thank you sir, ya...it will be a big task...but at the same time...I want to learn python also...at least to resolve the backup issue... to motivate my self also...

Comment: If you want to code it on our own, you will have to tell us more about your desired "backup" process. Do you just want to blindly upload all files? Or do you want to upload only the changed files?

Comment: Similar as we backup from local to external drive, if same file/folder it will be overwrites.